# How to monitor the progress of a plot

Tags: plotting, animation

Im a *Mathematica* newbie. Can someone tell me how to watch the progress of a plot. For example say I want to watch the curve `Exp[-x]` when `x` progresses from 0 to 5. How could I do that?

Comment: see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30540/how-do-i-put-a-monitor-into-cdf Assuming this is what you meant by "monitor progress of a plot", otherwise if you just mean how to see the plot itself being painted on the screen step by step, that is something else....you can use something like `Animate[Plot[Sin[a x], {x, -Pi, Pi}], {a, 1, 10}]` for this.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(116)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/116/121), [(5985)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5985/121)

Comment: Perhaps you mean something like `Manipulate[
 Plot[Exp[-x], {x, 0, a}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}], {a, 0.001, 5}]`?  The use of the word [`Monitor`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Monitor.html) is confusing to us old hacks. :)

Answer (score 7):

try this hack

```
Dynamic[Plot[Exp[-x], {x, 0, a}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-.1, 1.1}}]]
Do[a = i; Pause[.1], {i, 0.1, 5, .1}]
```

[image]

Comment: question about how to achieve the same effect: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84325/27539

Answer (score 1):

Building on the previous procedural 2 liner posted by Nassar, perhaps this functional approach is what you mean?  For more information, take a look at "Animate the Zeta Function" in Documentation.

```
Animate[
 Dynamic[
  Plot[Exp[-x], {x, 0, i}, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-.1, 1.1}}]
 ]
 , {i, 0, 5}
]
```