# How does progress monitor of Neural Network in Mathematica 11.1.0 work

Tags: front-end, dynamic, neural-networks

I was implementing my own progress monitor by appending loss of each step into a List and Dynamically ListPlot it. However, this method will cause memory insufficiency and significant laggy of frontend.

I would like to know how the very new Neural Network package monitors its training progress.
[image: Training Progress]

Comment: Repeated `Append` is a common performance pitfall because *Mathematica*'s lists are not linked lists but rather arrays. If you use a linked list then it will be a lot faster. I don't know anything about the Neural Networks package but I do wonder how it determines that training will require 5346 rounds in this case. From the plot it looks like it is already close to converging having done only a tenth of this many rounds.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks! If a max round/time number is not specified, it will automatically calculate one. But the documentation doesn't mention about how.

Comment: regarding the problem of plotting dynamically without the slow-down given by append, see this related post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/84348/27539

Answer (score 5):

It uses `` bag = Internal`Bag[] `` to create an empty bag, `` Internal`StuffBag[bag, val] `` to add values to the bag, and `` Internal`BagPart[bag, All] `` to convert the contents of the bag to a packed array.