# ProgressIndicator from Package to user interface

Tags: packages

I am trying to get the progress indicator bar from my package to the user interface. I am failing badly. I created an mini code that mimics my main code. Here I keep track of a paralleltable.

Some how I need to take the value of the progress indicator out from the loop and package to the interface.

Here is the main code:

```
Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
"DummyPackage.wl"}]];
 Panel[DynamicModule[{np = 100, nd = 30, Res1 = 1.0, 
 Res2 = ProgressIndicator[0]}, 
 Column[{Style["Random", "Function"] , 
Row[{"Digits ", InputField[Dynamic[nd]]}, Spacer[5]], 
Row[{"Precision ", InputField[Dynamic[np]]}, Spacer[5]],
(*Button[Style["Inputs",Green,Bold],Res2=ProgressIndicator[0]],*)

    Button[
 Style["Calculate", Green, Bold], {Res2 = ProgressIndicator[0], 
  Res = DummyPackage`myDummyF[nd, np]; Res1 = Res[[1]]; 
  Res2 = Res[[2]];}, Method -> "Queued"],
  Row[{Style["Result ", 12, Red], 
  InputField[Dynamic[Res1], FieldSize -> 30, Enabled -> False]}, 
  Spacer[15]],
  Row[{Style["Progress ", 12, Red], Dynamic[Res2]}, Spacer[15]],
  Button[Style["Save", Green, Bold], 
 NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], Interactive -> True]]
}],
Initialization :> (
Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
    "DummyPackage.wl"}]];)]]
```

And the package :

```
BeginPackage["DummyPackage`"]
LaunchKernels[$ProcessorCount];
myDummyF[nd_,np_]:=Module[{mat,mat2,aI,dl,d=0,tr=0},

 ns=200;
 mat=SetAccuracy[RandomReal[{-100,100},ns],nd];
 mat2=SetAccuracy[RandomReal[{-200,200},ns],nd];

  aI=ConstantArray[0,np];
 SetSharedVariable[d,tr];
 ParallelEvaluate[dl = 0];



 Monitor[aI=ParallelTable[If[Mod[dl++, Ceiling[nd/75]] == 0, d +=        Ceiling[nd/75]]; 
 If[iC==np,d==np];
 aI=SetAccuracy[mat.(mat2/iC^0.5),nd]
 ,{iC,np},DistributedContexts-> {"DummyPackage`"}];,tr=(d/np);];

  aInum=Apply[Plus,(aI/np)];

  Return[{aInum,ProgressIndicator[tr]}]];
  SetAttributes[{myDummyF},{ReadProtected,Protected,Locked}];
  EndPackage[];
```

>

Comment: I'm sorry for being picky about your posts but it is really in your interest to create **minimal** examples. You will get more attention. Are you sure saving, attributes or percision is related to the problem?

Comment: I thought the example was minimal. Two inputs, one array multiplication and two outputs. I could have removed the inputs nd, np but then the code does not feel complete.

Comment: As you can see by comments and upvotes, it wasn't :-/ Why removing inputs? What about things I've talked about?

Comment: You might be right or maybe it is not an interesting problem for the most.  And I did not delete anything :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it. To be honest, I am not sure how it is working. It is based on [@Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30540/how-do-i-put-a-monitor-into-cdf), there is only one thing in the setup a problem is "Null" appearing during the calculation. If I can find a solution for that I will update it in here. (FYI: Tracking the progress this way has a major hit on the performance)

```
Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
"DummyPackage2.wl"}]];
 Panel[DynamicModule[{np = 100, nd = 30, Res = {1.0, 0}, track = 0}, 
Column[{Style["Random", "Function"] , 
Row[{"Digits ", InputField[Dynamic[nd]]}, Spacer[5]], 
Row[{"Precision ", InputField[Dynamic[np]]}, Spacer[5]],
Button[Style["Calculate", Green, Bold], 
 Res = DummyPackage2`myDummyF[nd, np, Unevaluated[track]]
 , Method -> "Queued"],

Row[{Style["Result ", 12, Red], 
  InputField[Dynamic[Res[[1]]], FieldSize -> 30, 
   Enabled -> False]}, Spacer[15]],
Row[{Style["Progress ", 12, Red], 
  Dynamic[ProgressIndicator[track, {0, 1}]]}, Spacer[15]],
Button[Style["Save", Green, Bold], 
 NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], Interactive -> True]]
}],
Initialization :> (
Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[EvaluationNotebook[]], 
    "DummyPackage2.wl"}]];)]]
```

and the package

```
BeginPackage["DummyPackage2`"]
LaunchKernels[$ProcessorCount]
myDummyF[nd_,np_,track_]:=Module[{mat,mat2,aI,dl,d=0},

ns=200;
mat=SetAccuracy[RandomReal[{-100,100},ns],nd];
mat2=SetAccuracy[RandomReal[{-200,200},ns],nd];

aI=ConstantArray[0,np];


SetSharedVariable[d];
ParallelEvaluate[dl = 0];
Monitor[aI=ParallelTable[If[Mod[dl++, Ceiling[nd/75]] == 0, d +=    Ceiling[nd/75]]; 

aI=SetAccuracy[mat.(mat2/iC^0.5),nd]
,{iC,np},DistributedContexts -> {"DummyPackage2`"}];,
track=(d/np);];

iC=nd;
If[iC==nd,track=1];

aInum=Apply[Plus,(aI/np)];

Return[{aInum,track}];];
SetAttributes[{myDummyF},{ReadProtected,Protected,Locked}];
EndPackage[];
```